# How long DNS blacklist updates at Lotus Domino?

Tags: email, spam, ibm-domino, blacklist

As I kown,for performance,Lotus Domino will get the DNS blacklist from the `DNS blacklist sites` and save it in memory.

So,it is not real time?

For example:

> 2016/08/30 09:37:46   SMTP Server: iZ28mxuzo2dZ (27.75.142.47) connected
>
> 2016/08/30 09:37:49   SMTP Server: 41.225.94.52 connected
>
> 2016/08/30 09:37:49   SMTP Server: iZ28mxuzo2dZ (27.75.142.47) disconnected. 1 message received

But the query result from `spamhaus.org` is as below:

> IP Address 27.75.142.47 is listed in the CBL. It shows signs of being infected with a spam sending trojan, malicious link or some other form of botnet.
>
> It was last detected at 2016-08-30 04:00 GMT (+/- 30 minutes), approximately 1 hours ago.
>
> This IP is infected (or NATting for a computer that is infected) with the necurs spambot. In other words, it's participating in a botnet.
>   If you simply remove the listing without ensuring that the infection is removed (or the NAT secured), it will probably relist again.

My question is : is it not real time or How long it updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible option to find out the time will be to enables debug of DNS Blacklist lookups:

```
SMTPdebugcontrols = 3
SMTPdebugDNSBL=1
```

More infos [here](http://www.lotus-expert.com/en/notesini-reference/bycategory/41-debug/1703-smtpdebugdnsbl.html) and [here](http://www.lotus-expert.com/en/notesini-reference/bycategory/20-smtp_configuration/2182-smtpexpanddnsblstats.html).